# I have a WC Plugin running well. If the credit card goes wrong, my action "woocommerce_checkout_process" won't run again

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this WC plugin with another payment method... So far, so good... I put all the data and submit my form... So, the action function for "woocommerce_checkout_process" runs and I check if some of my fields are empty or something like that...

Nothing is empty, so the plugin process the payment... Ok, but now the page returns saying my credit card is without funds, so I can retry the payment with another credit card or change my payment method.

Here is the problem... Let's say I'll not change my method... So, I'll use my plugin again with the same payment method. When I click "Pay for Order", my action function for "woocommerce_checkout_process" doesn't run again and I cannot check any blank fields...

Any suggests why this happens and how to resolve?!

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify which plugin you are using? Or have you done any customization in plugin code

Comment: Hi, Navnish, tks! I'm trying to do a new plugin...

Comment: Actually, this is a new plugin for woocommerce

Comment: So can you share some code or something, so we can identify where the problem is. As in general its hard to tell what can goes wrong.

Comment: Well, in my plugin I have this code:

`add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'process_SE_payment_alimentacao');

function process_SE_payment_alimentacao() {

    if ( !isset($_POST['payment_type']) || empty($_POST['payment_type']) || $_POST['payment_type'] == "" )
        wc_add_notice( 'Please, select Payment Type', 'error' );

    if ( !isset($_POST['holder_cartao_al']) || empty($_POST['holder_cartao_al']) )
        wc_add_notice( 'Please, put Name of your Card', 'error' );
...`

And this function does not run when the user retry the payment...